# Format Number in ag grid 5210.15 to 5,210.15

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

How do you Format a number in an ag grid cell for example I have a quantity with decimals i.e.  5210.15 I would want this to return  5,210.15 I have seen a few ways to do it, but they completely forget the decimal points or they round them up. I don't need to round.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
function currencyFormatter(params) {
  return '$' + formatNumber(params.value);
}

function formatNumber(number) {
   return Math.floor(number).toFixed(2).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
}
```

Comment: I would recommend for you to check out http://numeraljs.com/. You can do the following for example: `var string = numeral(1000).format('0,0');` and it will return '1,000'

Comment: What have u tried? Please, add your code to the question

Comment: function currencyFormatter(params) {
    return '$' + formatNumber(params.value);
}

function formatNumber(number) {
   
    return Math.floor(number).toFixed(2).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
}

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it Just took off "Math.floor" and just worked with the Number. Because apparently Math.Floor rounds the number